# How to apply the foreign key constraints to the musicbrainz database?

Tags: postgresql, musicbrainz

I’m having difficulty applying the foreign keys to the postgres musicbrainz database.
I used these excellent instructions to get me this far:
https://bitbucket.org/lalinsky/mbslave
I have all of the data loaded in postgres.
I have primary keys and indexes created.

However, when I try to apply the foreign keys, I get this strange error:

```
musicbrainz@ip-10-217-5-18:/home/ubuntu/mbslave$ psql < sql/CreateFKConstraints.sql 
ERROR:  insert or update on table "annotation" violates foreign key constraint "annotation_fk_editor"
DETAIL:  Key (editor)=(51298) is not present in table "editor".
```

It seems to be erroring on the very first line of the SQL script:

```
ALTER TABLE annotation
   ADD CONSTRAINT annotation_fk_editor
   FOREIGN KEY (editor)
   REFERENCES editor(id);
```

I’m new to postgres and am having difficulty understanding this error message.

The first line leads me to believe that the foreign key constraint has already been created.
But I don’t think it has.

```
musicbrainz=> SELECT
musicbrainz->     tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name, 
musicbrainz->     ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
musicbrainz->     ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name 
musicbrainz-> FROM 
musicbrainz->     information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
musicbrainz->     JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
musicbrainz->       ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
musicbrainz->     JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
musicbrainz->       ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
musicbrainz-> WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND tc.table_name='annotation';
 constraint_name | table_name | column_name | foreign_table_name | foreign_column_name 
-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+---------------------
(0 rows)
```

The second line in the error message is confusing.
It sounds like it can’t find the id column in the editor table.
But it is there.

```
musicbrainz=> \d editor
                                      Table "musicbrainz.editor"
       Column        |           Type           |                      Modifiers                      
---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id                  | integer                  | not null default nextval('editor_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                | character varying(64)    | not null
 privs               | integer                  | default 0
 email               | character varying(64)    | default NULL::character varying
 website             | character varying(255)   | default NULL::character varying
 bio                 | text                     | 
 member_since        | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 email_confirm_date  | timestamp with time zone | 
 last_login_date     | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 edits_accepted      | integer                  | default 0
 edits_rejected      | integer                  | default 0
 auto_edits_accepted | integer                  | default 0
 edits_failed        | integer                  | default 0
 last_updated        | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 birth_date          | date                     | 
 gender              | integer                  | 
 area                | integer                  | 
 password            | character varying(128)   | not null
 ha1                 | character(32)            | not null
 deleted             | boolean                  | not null default false
Indexes:
    "editor_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "editor_idx_name" UNIQUE, btree (lower(name::text))
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE annotation
   ADD CONSTRAINT annotation_fk_editor
   FOREIGN KEY (editor)
   REFERENCES editor(id);
```

means that in the table `annotation`, the column `editor` in that table must also exist in the table `editor` under the column `id`.

Essentially, it's ensuring that all `editor` `id`'s that are used in `annotation` are present in the database.

This helps maintain *referential integrity*. Without the *Foreign Key* constraint, anything could be there, regardless of whether it was actually in the `editor` table or not, which could lead to a whole bunch of data-related issues.

The error message:

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "annotation" violates foreign key
>   constraint "annotation_fk_editor" DETAIL:  Key (editor)=(51298) is not
>   present in table "editor".

means that a row with the `id` of **51298** is not present in the table `editor`.

Is any data present in that table?

You can check in the FK constraint is enabled on `annotations` by doing a `\d` on that table like you did for `editor`. (You may need to do `\d+` to get all the info.)

Also, while I've not used *MusicBrainz* before, the BitBucket link contains two things which stand out to me which may be leading to your issue:

1. The setup instructions on the main page do not seem to be applying the FK constraints
2. The setup instructions also are making use of a *Python* wrapper called *mbslave-remap-schema.py*, which is doing some *sed*-like replacement of the SQL text to change schemas around and such, and piping the output of that into a wrapper of *psql* named *mbslave-psql.py* instead of *psql* directly
3. The sql files all appear to be schema-related, and the data itself appears to be imported from a dump using a different wrapper: `./mbslave-import.py mbdump.tar.bz2 mbdump-derived.tar.bz2` (apparently there is not a whole-database dump, or at least not one that is readily apparent)

Comment: That was it. The data that had been loaded into the database violated referential integrity. annotation.record='51298' exists, but editor.id='51298' does not.